# how to open an vi editor using c code read and close after some time

Tags: c, linux, vi

Hi I want to open a vi editor and using c code and as immediately the vi editor as to create a file called file.text and the cursor as to blink at the beginning of the file. and after some time i want to close it. please guide me how to do this..?

for EX: I want to read the barcode out which when read will print the data in the position where the cursor present so I want to open a file and print this data in that file and then save and close the file.please guide me how can I do this...???

Comment: Do  you need it to launch in an editor?  Or do you just need to write the data to an appropriate place within a file?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking but you could start with system("vi file.text");

Comment: I wonder he wants his C program to have an interface like VI (instead of using `scanf()` and other C functions), if I'm not wrong...

Comment: Why do you need VI editor to do this? It's a million times easier without it.

Comment: @fvdalcin since my barcode reader out which when read will print the data in the position where the cursor present so i want to save this in a file.how can I achieve this in other way since i don't have graphical view i want work in command line only.

Comment: @ShashankGupta how can I achieve this in other way since i don't have graphical view i want work in command line only.

Answer (score 0):

You start another program with [execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve). You wait with [sleep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep). And you terminate a program with [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill).

Comment: And don't forget to `fork`